# Take image out of video stream in ruby

Tags: ruby, video

I have a link to some video stream (web cam that is always recording some place). I would like to be able to take a screenshot of what ever is on that video stream at the moment a user goes to my app.

Can it be done and how?

I have looked but all I could find was for taking screenshots out of a movie/video, not out of a streaming video.

Comment: Is the video stream being displayed on a browser to the user at the time? Or are you needing to extract a frame using a Ruby client on the server side of your app?

Comment: The user never sees the stream, he should only see an image of the stream that it being display at the time he opens the app. But yes, I need to extract a frame from the stream (on server side) at the time user opens my app and show that frame(image) to him.

Comment: You need a streaming video client that Ruby can use to interact with the source. Whether or not one exists depends on the stream. What is the format and streaming technology (e.g. is it streaming over http: or does it start rtsp: or something else)?

Comment: this is the stream http://webcam.saan.tv/sljeme1

Answer (score 0):

I suspect ffmpeg connected to the streaming service as an input could probably extract thumbnails for you. You could either leave it running and pick up latest thumbnails, or fire it up with a system command and make it connect and emit a single screenshot. The latter would be more efficient and easier to code if you have a low number of hits, but would have a high latency on each request.

I did a quick search for you, but the most common uses of ffmpeg with streaming input is to re-format and re-stream, or to use it in personal video recorder setup. Ffmpeg is quite complex, so I could not complete the search in the time I have had so far.